# Is there a way to tell if the user clicks on a recent contact from the React Native share sheet?

Tags: react-native, ios-sharesheet

I'm trying to build a share sheet like the attached image, however, in my case it's possible for a contact to have multiple phone numbers.

If a contact has multiple phone numbers, then before directing the user to their texting app, I want to display a pop up with a phone number selector (that way the user can choose which phone number to send their message to).

I've looked at docs and other posts, but they don't mention if it's possible to not only tell if the user has clicked on a recent contact, but also to tell which contact they clicked on.

[image]

Is this possible or is is this something that's out of my control? (I know that there are many things on a style sheet that cannot be controlled on the developer's side so I was curious)